# Reference one of my own spreadsheets, within another, by its name

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to reference a spreadsheet that is within my own Google Drive, owned by me. The catch is, the spreadsheet changes. It will be a different spreadsheet ever day, with the date as it's filename.

I cannot reference it by spreadsheet key. I would like to reference it by name. I will accept the most far-fetched workaround at this point.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask]. By the way, the solution for this will require Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a [script](https://www.google.com/script/start/), using DriveApp service to access files by name. The following function fetches the spreadsheet key of the spreadsheet with today's date (in format 2016-04-29) as the name, and places it in cell A1. (You may want to change the cell, and the timezone which is GMT in the script).

Set the script to run daily, using Resources > This project's triggers. This will automatically keep the key up to date.

Then you can import data in the usual way, referring to the key in cell A1: `=importrange(A1, "Sheet1!B2:M200")`

```
function getKey() {
  var filename = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.open(files.next()).getId();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(ssId);
  }
}
```